# App architecture when using async/await on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, web-services, architecture, windows-phone, async-await

My question is related more to the architecture of an application that uses async and await.

Let's say I have a Web Service that returns a JSON formatted list of `Books` (or any object for that matter).

In a traditional implementation (without `async` and `await`) I would use three different classes: `BooksParser`, `BooksWebService` (singleton) and `BooksManager` (singleton) and in the `Page` where I need the list of books, I would have two delegate methods, one for success and one for error. So basically I would call `BooksManager` and `BooksManager` would call `BooksWebService`, the response would be downloaded asynchronously, passed to `BooksParser`, and `BooksParser` after parsing and creating the `List<Book>` would call on the main thread the delegate methods implemented in the `Page` (either the success one or the error one).

I am having dificulties in understanding how to make the transition and use `async/await`. Lets say I keep the same three clases. In BooksManager and as well BooksWebService I would change the methods called initially to something like `async Task<List<Books>> GetBooks(...).` and I would call this method on `BooksManager` from my `Page` and await for its response. But the problem is that I can't really understand how I would handle the errors (eg: no Internet connection, or 4xx status code from the WebService).

Should I do this using a try/catch approach or is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to use `try`/`catch`.

In your "library" `async` code (e.g., `BooksWebService`, `BooksParser`, `BooksManager`), you should be using `ConfigureAwait(false)` on every `await`. This instructs the compiler that you do *not* need to marshal back to the UI thread.

In your UI code (e.g., `Page`), you have a few options for "asynchronous initialization" that I describe [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html). Since this is actually part of the UI, you'll probably want to use an approach that looks like this:

```
public class MyPage : ...
{
  private async void OnLoad(...)
  {
    // Set up the "loading" state.

    try
    {
      var books = await BooksManager.GetBooks(...);

      // Transition to the "success" state.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // Transition to the "error" state.
    }
  }
}
```

The important thing to note is that with an asynchronous application, you have an additional "loading" state. What this looks like is up to you, but you will have to design it.

Comment: So inside my "library", I shouldn't use any try/catch to catch my custom exception. I should just catch the exception thrown by request.GetResponseAsync() somewhere at the BooksWebService level and create my own custom one, that would be relevant to the context of my app, an throw it so I could catch it in my UI code.

Comment: You can use `try`/`catch` if you need to handle an exception or convert/wrap it. That code would stay the same for asynchronous as it was in the synchronous solution. The main change that I'm recommending is the two "callbacks" for success/error. With `async` it's cleaner to represent a single "operation" (`Task`) that can complete with success/error. Other than that, your architecture should remain mostly the same.